# Attaching a pointer to a pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

In my program, I have a structure called `clock_thread` which is crucial for my threading system. It's basically a thread, which executes operations at a constant rate.

Sometimes a few functions need to synchronize with a `clock_thread`, but for that, they need the current `clock_thread`. I can't pass the `clock_thread` over the arguments. I know that I can get the current `pthread` via `pthread_self()`, but I somehow need to attach a pointer to the `pthread` which points to the `clock_thread` structure.

The only way I currently know of accomplishing this is to have a global array which keeps track of all `clock_thread`s, and when needed, compare the `pthread` of each `clock_thread` with the current 
`pthread` with `pthread_equal`.

As an example, a `clock_thread` does constantly invoke the method `do_stuff()`, which could theoretically do anything. The only purpose of the `clock_thread` is then calling the function, it has nothing to do with the functionality of the function. Then this function may call `perform_write`, which needs to change the state of another clock_thread. So it needs to know the current `clock_thread` but `do_stuff()` shouldn't need to pass the current `clock_thread` all the way through its logic. In the real function the `do_stuff` code is way more complex, and because of stylistic choices, I cann't pass the current `clock_thread` as an argument.

```c
struct clock_thread memory_thread;

void perform_read(uint16_t addr, uint16_t value) {
    //Needs to sync with other thread
    //But how
    clock_thread_sync(???, memory_thread);
}

void do_stuff() {
    //Do some stuff
    perform_write(addr, 0x1234);
}
```

Is there any better way of accomplishing this? I would like to avoid global variables as much as possible.

Comment: Please show the code. `I can't pass the clock_thread over the arguments` You can. You can pass all via arguments. That's why pthread's entrypoint has `void*` pointer as a argument.

Comment: I know that. I already pass the clock_thread structure to the looping code, but the problem is, that the thread invokes a system which has nothing to do with the threading system, and also through a stylistic choice, shouldn't know about the threading. But this system invokes another part of the program that needs to change the state of another `clock_thread`, and then it needs to synchronize

Comment: @Popa21 please don't describe your code but show it. You can [edit]  your question.

Comment: Doesn't that contradicts itself? You say, that the "system" (didn't you mean "program" or "function"?) shouldn't know about the threading implementation, then you say that it should know about clock_thread, which knows about threading system. That said - rewrite that "system" (program? library?) to allow passing callback. You have to show an MCVE - without it, there may be errors we both don't know about in your code.

Comment: With system I mean an part of the program which is responsible for som part of the program logic (it's a huge program).

Comment: So: `void perform_read(struct clock_thread *ct, uint16_t addr, uint16_t value) { ... clock_thread_sync(???, *ct); }` and `void do_stuff() {
    struct clock_thread memory_thread;
    //Do some stuff
    perform_write(&memory_thread, addr, 0x1234 );
}`

Comment: `memory_thread` is just an example for an thread. There may be any `clock_thread`. The ??? should correspond to the current `clock_thread`.

Comment: Ok. `struct args_s { struct clock_thread ct; unknown_type_that_you_want_to_pass_t value; };` `void perform_read(struct args_s *arg, uint16_t addr, uint16_t value) { ... clock_thread_sync(arg->value, &arg->ct);` `void do_stuff() { struct args_s args = { .value = ???, }; perform_write(&args, addr, 0x1234); }` I can do this all day. If you can pass any kind of context to your function, any pointer value, you can pass any data. Just specify memory `struct`ure, allocate memory for it, initialize and pass a pointer to the memory to your function.

Comment: I just noticed my own problems with my design choices. `do_stuff()` is designed to be called from anywhere. From a loop, from a `clock_thread`, ... . But `perform_read()` is desgined to be called from  a `clock_thread`. I need to overthink this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, because the `do_something()` function knows which thread it's in (another struct where it has a pointer to). The `perform_read()` now takes the current `clock_thread` as an argument